# Are all cables that have a USB-C connector automatically USB 3.0 or 3.1 compliant?

Tags: usb, usb-3, usb-3.1-type-c

I was talking to a guy in BestBuy regarding if the cable I was holding is 3.x compliant.  He said yes, it has a USB-C connector (as well as a USB-A connector) so it is 3.x compliant.  However, as I understand it, the letters refer to the exterior HW interface and the numbers describe the interior mechanism.  Who's right?

Comment: No not automatically, however it is quite likely that Bestbuy does not sell cables which don’t. So the seller might be right for his products.

Comment: @eckes, I am afraid quite opposite is true. BestBuy, Frys, etc. are usually selling garbage, non-certified USB products, whatever the cheapest one are. You need to really spend a lot of time finding few certified products there, if you are lucky.

Answer (score 4):

> Are all cables that have a USB-C connector automatically USB 3.0 or
> 3.1 compliant?

To put it simply, No, all USB Type-C cables are not created equal.  Benson Leung, a Google Engineer, has spent a considerable amount of time submitting USB Type-C cable reviews to Amazon.

He has hundreds of product reviews, but based on those reviews one can conclude, a manufacturer can produce a cable that technically works but does not actually conform to the actual USB standard.

[Benson Leung](https://www.amazon.com/gp/profile/amzn1.account.AFLICGQRF6BRJGH2RRD4VGMB47ZA/ref=cm_cr_srp_d_pdp?ie=UTF8)

> However, as I understand it, the letters refer to the exterior HW
> interface and the numbers describe the interior mechanism.

I assume by "letters" you mean the indication what type of connector it is? The cable must conform to the same standard as the port, USB connectors outside of Type-C connectors, are backward compatible with previous standards.

> Who's right?

I wouldn't put much weight on the knowledge of a random BestBuy employee. I wouldn't say you were correct either.  As I pointed out, one person you can trust will give you accurate advice, is of course, Benson Leung.

> To lead off, my verdict: This cable does not follow the USB Type C
> specification Release 1.2. To find the specification, please go to
> usb.org, and look under developers/usbtypec.
>
> The USB Type-C specification defines two types of Type-C cables:
>
> - Section 3.4.1 USB Full-Featured Type-C Cable Assembly for cables that support SuperSpeed operation
> - Section 3.4.2 USB 2.0 Type-C Cable Assembly for cables that only support USB 2.0.
>
> Since Aukey advertises that this cable is capable of 10gbps operation
> and calls it a "USB 3.1 Gen 1" cable at least once in their product
> description, I will judge them based on Section 3.4.1 for a
> "Full-Featured" Type-C cable.
>
> My analysis shows these serious problems with this cable, based on my
> visual analysis, and using my "Twinkie" PD Analyzer as well as Total
> Phase's Advanced Cable Tester.
>
> 1. Missing USB certification and SuperSpeed logo This cable is not certified by USB-IF and lacks any identifying logo on the cable itself
>    and on the box. This means that the cable is completely anonymous and
>    a user may simply forget what kind of cable it is and not know it is
>    one that supports SuperSpeed.
>
> It is absolutely expected, given the possible complexity and range of
> functionality of a C-to-C cable that official USB-IF logos be used,
> and USB-IF certification must be done to reduce customer confusion.
>
> 2. Missing required e-marker electronic identifier chip USB Type-C Specification Section 4.9 "Electronically Marked Cables" states, "All
>    USB Full-Featured Type-C cables shall be electronically marked."
>
> In my testing with a Twinkie PD Analyzer and the Total Phase Advanced
> Cable Tester, this cable lacks the required e-marker entirely, and
> will not work with sources and sinks that depend on checking the
> capabilities of the cable using the identifier chip.
>
> 3. Missing 6 required data carrying wires. 4 SuperSpeed wires and 2 SBU wires USB Type-C Specification Table 3-10 "USB Full-Featured
>    Type-C Standard Cable Assembly Wiring" lists 16 wires that are
>    mandatory for that type of cable.
>
> In my testing of the Aukey CB-CD7 using the Total Phase Advanced Cable
> Tester, only 9 wires are present. This cable is missing the following
> data wires: SDPp3, SDPn3, SDPp4, SDPn4, SBU_A, SBU_B.
>
> As a result, this cable fails when Alternate Modes are used, the most
> common of which is DisplayPort Alternate Mode. When I tried using this
> cable to connect my Chromebook to an LG 4K monitor with USB-C, the
> cable failed to carry the 4k video to the monitor because of the 6
> missing wires.
>
> 4. High IR drop on GND:
>    89.55 mΩ measured. 83.00 mΩ allowed by the USB Type-C specification. This may result in poor performance charging or no charging at all as
>    high IR drop on GND may distrupt PD communication over CC.
> 5. SuperSpeed TX and RX fail signal integrity at 10gbps. Aukey claims that this is a USB 3.1 Gen 2 cable capable of 10gbps, but the Advanced
>    Cable Tester on C-C / SS Gen 2 / 3A / SI default settings marks the
>    cable as a fail for 10ghz signal integrity.
>
> Aukey, please contact me if you have any questions on how to fix this
> cable. I would highly recommend stop selling this cable immediately,
> as it is at best a deceptive product for consumers.
>
> For consumers, I do not recommend buying this cable, as it will not
> work with Chromebooks, MacBook Pros, or other Type-C devices that use
> DisplayPort or other Alternate Modes, as is expected of USB 3.1 Full
> Featured C-to-C cables. It is NOT futureproof like true Full-Featured
> C-to-C cables.

[Aukey CB-D36 violates the USB spec; Fails in Alternate Modes because of missing wires, and missing required e-marker.](https://www.amazon.com/gp/review/R1GW3RGC4Y1PFC?ref_=glimp_1rv_cl)

Comment: Ok, yes, there are bad cables, but *if* what it says on the box is correct, is a cable with a USB type C connector automatically USB 3.x compliant?  If so, which, 3.0 or 3.1?

Comment: @Adrian - Those products on Amazon make a claim, and the Google Engineer has proven them wrong.  I would like to point out, I have already answered that question, there is a reason I used the particular example of those reviews to answer this question.

Comment: I understand that.  But *if* we did go by the specs, is a cable with a USB type C connector automatically USB 3.x compliant? If so, which, 3.0 or 3.1?

Comment: It can be USB 3.0 compliant.  I have several USB 3.0 Type-A to Type-C cables.  I suggest you read the USB Standard Group's documentation on Type-C if you want to learn more.

Comment: [There are USB 2.0 Type-C cables](https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-USB-Type-C-2-0-Cable/dp/B01GGKZ3MM/ref=cm_cr_srp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8) you are basically asking the wrong question.  A Type-C cable can be meet any USB specification it wants.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was asking.  The external interface has nothing to do with the internals.

Comment: @Adrian - Internals of the cable?  It absolutely does.

Answer (score 1):

The official USB Implementers Forum standards for USB Type-C connector usage do have provisions for creation of USB Type-C cables that only support USB 2.0. So you can have a USB Type-C cable that is correctly designed and manufactured and fully within spec and passes USB-IF certification and carries the official USB logo, but only supports USB 2.0. Not only for C-to-A cables, but even for C-to-C cables.

However, I would expect such cables to be exceedingly rare, especially a C-to-A USB 2.0 only cable, because there is no market demand for them, they aren’t much cheaper to make than one that supports USB 3.0, and anyone who picked one up accidentally would feel ripped off and return it as defective as soon as they realized it didn’t support USB 3.0.

Tip: If you have a cable with a Type-A connector on it and you want to know if it probably supports USB 3.0, see if the plastic inside the connector is blue. USB 3.0-compliant connectors are usually color coded blue inside. If you’re still not sure, look deep inside the connector and see if you see a row of 5 square contacts behind the usual row of 4 oblong contacts (on female USB 3.0 ports, the 5 square contacts are near the front). Manufacturers are unlikely to pay for the slightly more expensive connectors with the extra contacts if they didn’t intend to make a USB 3.0 cable. Of course, even if it’s blue, has extra contacts, and even carries the USB SuperSpeed logo, you never know if it might have been made by some ripoff artist company. There are a lot of crappy cables of all sorts out there, and some manufacturers have even brazenly pirated and misused the copyrighted official certification logos of the USB-IF.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is clearly given in Section 3 of Type-C Specifications, Ver.1.3. The current spec can be found as a part of [USB 3.2 standard release, on USB.ORG](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb_32_112017.zip)

In brief, there are two basic kinds of Type-C cables - the ones that support Super Speed rates (and have two pairs of Tx-Rx lines), and the ones which are carrying USB 2.0 wire only for data transmission. So, being any of this kind makes any cable (that has at least one end as Type-C) "USB 3.1 compliant", formally speaking.

Apparently the question is about whether a cable is USB 3.1 Gen.1 or Gen.2 compliant. The answer is a bit convoluted.

First, ANY legacy cable assembly (the one that has one end of Type-A/B/micro) **must be qualified for Gen.2 data rate** - 10 Mbps. Period. Therefore it must have all legacy connectors of USB 3.1 Gen.2 modification. This is a requirement of Type-C specs. So yes, any cable that has Type-C on one end must be automatically compliant to 10 Gbps data rate.

For "full-featured" (Type-C to Type-C) cables, there could be cables that can qualify only for USB 3.1 Gen1 rates, typically the longer ones, 2 m plus, and shorter C-C cables (< 1m) can be qualified for USB 3.1 Gen.2 rates.

However, this is all valid only for cables that are **USB-IF certified**, for which they can carry a USB 3.1 Gen2 logo, and must have TID number - Test ID. The cables must conform to a sizable set of parameters - certain cable insertion loss with frequency, near and far end crosstalk (NEXT and FEXT), total 30 pages of requirements. There are a lot of tests to comply, and one must have quite a special equipment and test rigs to make/design a good compliant cable.

Good luck in finding these cables (as of Jan 2018).

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same spec, and one is not included in the other.
You are correct that USB *type-A*, *type-B*, and *type-C* are standards defining the **physical** interface. USB *1.x*, *2.x*, and *3.x* are standards defining the **protocol** transmitted over the wires.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) and [usb.org](http://www.usb.org/home).

Comment: It is more than just the **protocol**.  Protocol is has to do with the data transmission.  From what I've read, USB x.y also defines other internal physical aspects, including how much power it can handle.

Comment: Yes, it does reference voltages, at least in the Battery Charging Spec, but I wouldn't really call that a physical spec like say, wire gauge. I could be wrong, I'm certainly not an expert on the subject. I'm erroring on the side of oversimplification in order to provide a simple answer to a simple question.

Comment: @mjb2kmn - The USB specification indicates what wires should be connected to which wires and what those wires should be connected to (i.e. a resistor,ect).which would be a physical specification.  Really good answers stand by themselves. If I were to delete my answer your reference to my answer wouldn't make sense. shouldn't

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Ramhound. The main point is that while USB 3.0 might specify a few physical characteristics, it is a different standard from USB type-c that defines the shape of the connector and many other physical specifications.

Comment: The gist of your answer is correct. The USB-C connector is covered by a spec separate from the USB release spec. It was released about the same time as 3.1 and meets/supports the 3.1 requirements. The C standard facilitates a collection of usage concepts supported by 3.1.  3.1 doesn't require the C connector & vice versa. The USB version releases (numbers) define everything required to achieve specific speed targets, including hardware and protocols (except for the C connector).  The C connector can be used in ways outside the USB 3.1 spec, so it doesn't automatically ensure 3.1 compliance.